# What is the favorable naming convention for methods or properties returning a boolean value in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, naming-conventions, boolean

I've seen all of these:

- `is_valid`
- `is_valid?`
- `valid?`

Is there a preferred one?

EDIT: More conditionals:

- `has_comment` `has_comment?` `comment?`
- `was_full` `was_full?` `full?`

Please do add more descriptive examples.

Answer (score 8):

I think the convention is mostly to add a '?' at the end of the method instead of 'is'

- `valid?`

Answer (score 1):

In favor of trying the code to be 'natural language' like, is_valid? should be most suitable for me. Lets show an example:

if @order.is_valid?
  @order.save
end

Comment: I agree. And what about other conditionals.. has_comment? is more descriptive than comment?.

Comment: Using the question mark seems exaggerated, if a conditional is prefixed (IMHO).

Comment: You are right,thinking about it again, standard convention is ".valid?" (eg .nil?, .empty?, .blank?), but I am still fan of human like code.